# Is it possible to train a neural network with "splited" output

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

**Is it possible to consider the output of one neural network as two or more sets of outputs ?**

I explain myself a bit more (in a q learning context):

> Imagine i have two agents in the same environement and each agents
>   have a different  amount of performable actions. Both of the agents
>   will have the same input vector containing environnemental variables
>   to chose their actions.

The question is :

**Can I use a unique neural network to control both agents ?**

One exemple:

> Agent 1 have 3 performable actions and Agent 2 have only 2 performable
>   actions. An important thing is that the agent will have to work
>   cooperatively to maximize the reward. Can i use 1 neural network with
>   5 outputs to chose the best action to do for both agents ? like the
>   first 3 outputs of the network will be the Q values for the first
>   agent and the 2 others will be the Q values for agent 2. My reward
>   function will always be based on the global results, each agents will
>   not have specific reward.

Is it possible ? Because i didn't find anything talking about that.
If you need more precisions just ask.

I also know that a possible solution should be to make a network with 3 * 2 outputs and each output would be a couple of actions (1 action for each agent), but i really want to know if someone already did someone like i explained before or just if someone know that can't work and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about this specifically for reinforcement learning, but multi-output neural networks are very common in the literature.

If you want a single network to control both agents, it's probably a good idea to share the early stages of the network, before separating the network in two distinct branches, with a few layers in each branches.

For an example of how to deal with multiple outputs, you can check out [this link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/04/keras-multiple-outputs-and-multiple-losses/).

Comment: Thank for your answer, i'm gonna try both then ! thank for the link

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer, please mark it as resolving your problem, so that this question gets resolved.

Comment: I'll wait 1 or 2 days to see if someone has already experimented that, because i see one difference with the link u gave me and it's that i will use only one loss because of the common reward

Comment: If you're going to be using a single joint loss for both agent, you can actually probably conceptually consider them as a single agent that encompasses the state of both agents and then using two branches doesn't really make sense anymore.

Comment: Yeah that is true, but that is why i will try both ideas, one with separate branches and differents rewards and losses and one as you defined it